# How to initialise a thread-local with type Map using ThreadLocal.withInitial?

Tags: java, initialization, thread-local

I'm trying to initialise a thread-local of type Map using "ThreadLocal.withInital" method

I can proceed with setting a new ThreadLocal and adding a setter method to proceed with the initialisation. But I'm trying to find a way whether this can be done via initial.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Map<Date, Boolean>> dateBooleantl = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

Expected Output:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Map<Date, Boolean>> dateBooleantl = ThreadLocal.withInitial(<Hash-map that is set with a predefined date and a boolean>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Map<Date, Boolean>> dateBooleantl = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
        Map<Date, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(new Date(), true);
        //do other stuff...
        return map;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can this statement lambda be replaced with expression lambda?

Comment: What do you mean by expression lambda? Are you looking for a one-line solution?

Comment: Yes, when i do something like this: 
ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
     return new HashMap<Date, Boolean>(){{
      put(new Date(), true);
    }};
  });

IntelliJ suggests that this can be turned into expression lambda.

Comment: Consider that Map has a putAll method but it takes another Map as input. Also consider that in this way the code would became unreadable, and I think that sometimes it is better to keep it readable. Also you would not have any performance improvement from doing this.

Comment: Fair Enough. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

ThreadLocal.withInitial method takes a Functional parameter, so it can be a Lambda, like this:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Map<Date, Boolean>> dateBooleantl = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
    Map<Date, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(new Date(), true);
    return map;
});
```